# error: failed to parse manifest caused by: no `package` section found

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have installed **C++ 2015 Tools** from Microsoft as described in the installation section.

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Mg Sein\Desktop\rust\hello_world>cargo build
error: failed to parse manifest at `C:\Users\Mg Sein\Desktop\rust\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  no `package` section found.
```

This is the directory of project file:

[image: directory of project file]

I added the path variable for `cargo`:

[image: add path variable for cargo]

This is the contents of Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Mg Sein"]
[dependencies]
```

Comment: The error message is about `…\rust\Cargo.toml`, but you only showed us `…\rust\hello_world\Cargo.toml`.  `…\rust\Cargo.toml` shouldn't be needed, maybe try deleting (or renaming) it.

Comment: I change the name but the error still exists. Here is the error.Caused by:
  no targets specified in the manifest
  either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be present @Stefan

Answer (score -1):

I changed from `cargo.toml` to `Cargo.toml` directly inside the Rust project folder and changed `hello.rs` to `main.rs` directly inside the Rust project folder.

From this,

[image: before renaming file]

to this,

[image: after renaming file]

Comment: This seems wrong on every level.  What is the `hello_world` folder now for? Everything should be inside that folder, `rust` doesn't sound like a sane project folder name. It also seems you didn't call `cargo build` in the `hello_world` folder like you claimed above.